# How to edit this XSLT in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts

I have a web part that when I create a  page for a restaurant , it will show in a web part. If I do not create any page, the web part is empty.

My question is how to edit this XSLT. If I do not create any page, it will show a sentence :you have nothing." Otherwise, it will list a page that I create.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, xslt stylesheets are store in the Style Library. If your web part is a content query web part, you can create a copy of ItemStyle.xsl and modify it as you like. See [How to: Customize XSL for the SharePoint Content By Query Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for a detailed guide.